# what is the best way to know if it is the first time that the application is open in the day?

Tags: c#, .net, logic

I'm looking for an example code how to know if it is the first time that the application is open in the day?
I tried saving the current date in a .ini file and an key named open  defined with boolean value and then compare:

```
DateTime.Now.Substract(*old date from .ini file*).TotalMinutes >= 0
```

and after this, set open key in .ini file as true. how to implement it? there an way more easy to do it?

I need know of it because in first time that the application was open I'II update a list in database.

any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why the extra boolean? Having the date should be enough. If the date is not today, then it wasn't opened today.

Comment: Is your application multi-user?  Do you need to know whether this is the first time the app was run on a given workstation? by a given user on that workstation? or do you need to know if it is the first time for the whole installation?

Comment: A singleton with application scope, keeping last-use-date in a variable?

Comment: Do you want if it was opened within a given day, or within a 24 hour period of last being opened?  For example should opening it at 8PM and at 1AM the following day count as it being open on two days once, or in one day twice?

Comment: Keep in mind that you may want to use the DateTime.Now.AddDays(minus) may get better results your dealing with DateTime here is an example of what I have used to see if a WriteTime of a file has changed string testDate = String.Format("{0}", DateTime.Now.AddDays(-Convert.ToInt32(strDateDelay)), "dd mmm yyyy");

Comment: @Alfabravo: How would that survive application restarts?

Comment: if you store the dd and the next day it runs you could check it by using something like this adjusting the variable any way to fit your needs but it should give you an idea string ldate = string.Format("{0}", Convert.ToDateTime(strCurDate).Day - 1, "dd"); Application restarts would only survive if he were tracking the yyyy mm dd hh:mm:ss good question

Comment: @R0MANARMY It can't. Wouldn't. Shouldn't. Couldn't. Won't. You Shall not pass!

Comment: the only way that might pass is if he were to create a Mutex making sure that only one instance of the application could run.. but I am probably taking his simple question further than what he's expecting

Answer (score 2):

Per user in [Application Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) would be the place I would choose.

Answer (score 0):

"Best" is a moving target.  For one app, one method may be best, but another app may need something completely different.

That said, you need a few concepts to be covered:

1. Some place to remember the "last opened" time.
2. Some code to check the time, update it, and do the once-per-day work.

From your question, #2 is pretty straightforward, once you know what #1 should be.  So, here are some potential options for #1.

1. Database (in a table tied to something like a user id)
2. Ini file (as you mentioned)
3. An xml file (maybe even inside app.config)

Comment: will need a check for 11:59:59 could he write a TimeSpan method check if (((TimeSpan)(DateTime.Now - fiUpdateFileFile.LastWriteTime)).TotalHours < 24) but checking against the time that's stored in the .INI / .config file TotalHours will also work if he wanted to check

Answer (score 0):

See my comments in your question regarding whether you are tracking on a lone workstation/multi-user, etc -- that will dictate where you store your date time (in the database, in machine-level scope, in user-level scope, etc).

Now as for what you store, if you are a multi-user app (or even mobile, like on a phone or laptop), don't forget to consider timezones.  For that matter, don't forget to consider daylight savings time. (those changes in time could cause you to think that a day has passed, when it has not, or vice-versa).

I would recommend that you always store the time in UTC, and always compare in UTC:

```
// save the start time:
var startTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
(save the start time)
...
// comparing the times:
// also, are you worried about doing the check once per 24 hours, or do you want to go by calendar date?
// you already have code that does a once per 24hr check, so I will show code that goes by calendar days
if(startTime.Date < DateTime.UtcNow.Date)
  // hasn't run today
else
 // has run today
```

Comment: Or DateTime.UtcNow which I've read somewhere is even much faster. The following article claims > 100x performance improvement of .UtcNow or .Now. http://totaldotnet.com/Tip/ShowTip24_UseDateTimeUtcNow.aspx